# Immigrating to Germany as an Israeli citizen with a criminal record and a German spouse

Tags: germany, resident-permit, eu-spouses

Around 7-10 years ago, I had issues with our army. I deserted due to my health and financial issues, since I had to pay the surgery and the hospitalization and the treatment.

So I have been sitting 3 times in army jail. Overall it was around 1 year all together.

Does it has an influence on my application to join my German Spouse? For more information: I never had any problems with the police not even a parking ticket or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, no you should be fine. Germany does not care what you did in your home country.

The only exceptions to *all* visas are crimes that you could be deported for anyway. That's crimes that violate the safety and public order of Germany. There is no list one could check crimes against, but it's meant for war criminals and acts of terrorism. I don't think that anyone would argue deserting a foreign army in peacetime is an act to endanger Germany's public order.

Answer (score 1):

militar rules/laws are quite different to civil laws and in your case you are just fine, what you did is a military felony and Germany is only interested about if your "Criminal records" can represent a future social issue by in case of recurrence

Is they ask, you can tell the truth and everything will be fine...